# create a new variable automaticaly

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, while-loop, automation

This is a general question. But an answer in JavaScript would suit me the best.
I'm searching for a way to create variables after a pattern automatically.
For example, I want to create a while-loop in which a variable gets declared. In set loop, I want to create the variable car1. However, in the next loop pass I want to do the same  thing BUT call the Variable car2 this time.
I'll try to write it in pseudocode:

```js
//this should happen in the first loop
while(true){
  var car1 = 1 + 2;
  console.log(car1)
}

//this should happen in the second loop
while(true){
  var car2 = 1 + 2;
  console.log(car)
}

//In both cases "3" should be the output. But different Variables
```

Contrary to this example. I want to do all this in a single while loop. And on every while loop, a new variable should be created. So car1,car2,car3,car4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can it be a `for` loop instead?

Comment: not really. I want to create a new Variable until the user decides to stop the loop. so a for loop wouldn't be perfect

Comment: why do you want to create multiple variables? perhaps if you can explain that, a viable alternative can be suggested - should the variables be global scope or function scope? (block scope wouldn't make sense for obvious reasons)

Comment: Is there maybe a way of including a Variable into the name of a Variable. Like this

`let x = 0;

while(true){
  x++;
  let car[ + x] = 1 + 2;
}
`
@JaromandaX

Comment: no, that isn't javascript - should the variables be global scoped or function scoped?

Comment: I want to create multiple variables for my project. The project is a text-based race game. So after a Car (object) has completed the race, I want to save all it's stats (for example the time it needed). But while programming I don't know how many racers there will be @JaromandaX

Comment: While this is possible in JavaScript, it is not recommended. The literal answer: `globalThis['car' + x] = 1 + 2`. But please don't. Almost every time someone asks about dynamically created variables, it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead, the actual answer is: use a structure, such as array: `cars = []` and `cars[x] = 1 + 2`.

Comment: use an Array ... how else can you keep track?

Comment: @Amadan - you can of course use `eval`

Comment: @JaromandaX Function and global scope will both work

Comment: @JaromandaX You can, and if you need to make local variables you can't use the `globalThis` trick; but that is an even worse solution :) An array (or an object, or a Map) is the only sane answer for this. (I mean, you didn't have to delete your answer — it _is_ an answer — as long as there is a disclaimer there, as you did add)

Comment: Yeah but is there a way to create "infinite" array entries automatically? 
so create an array named Cars = [] and then create a new entry on each loop pass?
@Amadan

Comment: @Amadan - I agree, the only sane option is some object to store the cars

Comment: @asgr - no, you can't create infinite array, since your computer can't hold that much data

Comment: Infinite no, but millions, yes. It is very rare for most users to have an array not be sufficient.

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't mean infinite. sorry. But how do I create a new entry on each for loop pass?

Comment: `let raceMore = true, cars = []; for (let race = 0; raceMore; race++) { cars.push(1 + 2); raceMore = prompt("Race more?") !== 'no'; }` or you can replace `cars.push(1 + 2)` with `cars[race] = 1 + 2`, both should be equivalent in this example. It would be beneficial to review [array tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays).

Comment: @asgr You can refer to my answer and use for loop to achieve dynamic creation

Comment: @Amadan ur proposal fits my question perfectly. Do you want to propose it as an answer to get those yummy points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use an array and add an item every loop iteration or a hash map with a naming convention you set for the keys

Comment: That would be perfect. But how do I create a new item every iteration?

Comment: In case of an array , you could use push to add to the end of the array or unshift to add to the beginning. For a Map type you could use set(key,value) while making your key dynamic for example using key='car'+x while x is the loop counter

Comment: why would you accept this answer if you don't understand it @asgr

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) or [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

```js
function nameFunction(name, f) {
  return {
    [name](...args) {
      return f(...args)
    }
  }[name]
}

// use globalThis
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  const funcName = `car${i}`;
  const func =
    nameFunction(funcName, () => console.log(`this is car ${i}`));
  globalThis[funcName] = func;
}

car1(); car2(); car3();

// use window
for (let i = 4; i <= 6; i++) {
  const funcName = `car${i}`;
  const func =
    nameFunction(funcName, () => console.log(`this is car ${i}`));
  window[funcName] = func;
}

car4(); car5(); car6();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link will help you with this problem.

[JS Dynamic Variable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript/)

Here they have discussed 2 ways of solving the problem. (One with "eval" and the other with "windows" object.